# Dynamically resize the line drawn on canvas using touch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas

In my android application i have to get an image from the WebView and then add annotations on it. So, far i have sucessfully been able to achieve that. The problem is that i could not find a solution to how to dynamically scale them once a particular annotation is drawn. For insatance a straight line,a circle etc.

```
private void setupDrawing() {
    // get drawing area setup for interaction
    Log.d("onCreate", "" + "setupDrawing");
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawRect = new Rect();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // detect user touch
    Log.d("Event", "onTouchEvent");
    if (canDrawFreeHand == true) {
        Log.d("", "canDrawFreeHand true");

        Log.d("Fag", "Got the Free hand flag " + currentflag);
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Log.d("freehand", "draw");
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Log.d("freehand", "Drawing..");
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("freehand", "Drawn");
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
```

}

I want to scale them in such a way that after some annotation is draw, when the user clicks on that drawing. It is ready to be scaled.